# "and to assert it, the whole structure"

Tags: syntax

*A more fundamental question might also be raised here: why does the revolutionary Truth-Event entail violence? Because it is enacted from the symptomal point (or torsion) of the social body, from the point of impossibility of the social totality — its subject is the “part of no-part” of society, those who, although they are formally part of society, are denied a proper place within it. **This is society’s “point of truth,” and to assert it, the whole structure whose point of impossibility this point is must be annihilated, suspended***.

Source: https://www.jacobinmag.com/2011/05/the-jacobin-spirit/

I am not able to understand the passage in bold in terms of its syntax. It seems to me as if the part beginning with "the whole structure…" were not connected to the preceding one. Is it possible to parapharase this part in this way: *This is society’s “point of truth,” and to assert it means that the whole structure whose…* Or is the sentence parsing different?

Comment: This article has a larger percentage of big words than anything I have read recently...

Comment: This is a confusing statement, but as far as I can tell it means "This is society's "point of truth" and to assert it the whole structure (whose point of impossibility is the same as the "point of truth") must be annihilated. The comma after "assert it" seems off though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is society’s “point of truth,” and to assert it, the whole
>   structure whose point of impossibility this point is must be
>   annihilated, suspended.

This is society's point-of-truth, and to assert it (the point-of-truth), the whole structure, whose point-of-impossibility is this point-of-truth, must be annihilated, (must be) suspended.

whose point-of-impossibility this point-of-truth *is* = whose point-of-impossibility is this point-of-truth

Consider a man holding up a dog collar for you to see:

**The dog, whose collar this is, has run away from its owner.**

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to make out the meaning because clauses are run together without any hints. I would interpret it this way:

> This is society’s “point of truth,” and to assert it, the whole structure (whose point of impossibility this point is) must be annihilated, suspended.

I don't care for the repetitive use of "point". This seems to muddle what the author is actually trying to say.